# Can you abbreviate dot notation access to properties in Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

I have a UIButton that I need to change the label text for lots of times in different contexts. This means writing

```
myButton.titleLabel?.text = "my text"
```

a lot.

Is there any way the path to the `.text` property can be abbreviated, to make my code easier to read and save a bit of typing? Ideally something like:

```
myButtonText = "my text"
```

Is this possible in Swift? Assigning `myButton.titleLabel?.text` to a 'myButtonText' variable doesn't work, as setting the value of the variable only affects that variable, it's not passed back through to the original property.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a [computed property](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID259)?

```
var myButtonText: String {
    get {
        button.title(for: .normal) ?? ""
    }
    set {
        button.setTitle(newValue, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
myButtonText = "Hello world!"
print(myButtonText)
```

[image: Button says "Hello world!", "Hello world!" printed in console]

Note: You shouldn't access [`titleLabel`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1623992-titlelabel) directly - instead, use...

- [`title(for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624022-title) for retrieving the title
- [`setTitle(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibutton/1624018-settitle) for setting the title

Comment: Works like a dream @aheze, thanks! For info, I found making myButtonText an optional String type avoids the need to add a nil coalescer to the getter. Not a big deal here, but if using this method for other UIKit objects like UIImage, it helps.